# Can someone tell me why did mongo generate this _id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I'm working on an ecommerce website. I have created the models: user, order, product. Everything works as expected, but mongodb ( or mongoose maybe idk ) decided to generate _id for a product while making a post request of an order. I have no clue why it did that and if it is the norme, how can I use since it's a different _id from what I have in my products list??

Here's what my models look like:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    street: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zip: String,
    // default: "Not provided" // errore has occurred after adding this line
  },
  payment_info: {
    card_number: String,
    expiration_date: String,
    cvv: String
  },
  cart: [{
    product: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product'
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    }
  }],
  orders: [{
    order: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Order'
    },
    status: String
  }],
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

```
// product model

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    
    {
        "name": {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        "description": {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        "price": {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        "createdAt": {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        "users": [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        ],
        "updatedAt": {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }
);
```

```
// order model

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        "user": {
          "type": mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          "required": true,
          "ref": "User"
        },
        "items": [
          {
            "product": {
              "type": mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              "required": true,
              "ref": "Product"
            },
            "quantity": Number,
            "price": Number
          }
        ],
          "shippingAddress": {
            "street": String,
            "city": String,
            "state": String,
            "zip": String,
            "country": String
          },
          "billingAddress": {
            "street": String,
            "city": String,
            "state": String,
            "zip": String,
            "country": String
          },
        "total": Number,
        "status": String,
        "createdAt": Date,
        "updatedAt": Date
    }
);
```

```
// Here's the post request that I made: ( I'm using rest extension in vs code )

POST http://localhost:8080/orders/order/1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "user": "63f7ac9b0a9461e9e1befb02",
    "items": [
        {
            "product": "63f79b7f1aee39f2d8958553",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 4000
        }
    ],
    "shippingAddress": {
          "street": "",
          "city": "String",
          "state": "String",
          "zip": "String",
          "country": "String"
        },
        "billingAddress": {
          "street": "String",
          "city": "String",
          "state": "String",
          "zip": "String",
          "country": "String"
        },
    "total": "4000",
    "status": "Not Deliverd"
}
```

```
Here's the response from the server: 
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 540
ETag: W/"21c-dZAoGrQsHi8Ob/1ow/tHFpe5P/8"
Date: Fri, 24 Feb 2023 11:26:46 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "orderCreated": {
    "user": "63f7ac9b0a9461e9e1befb02",
    "items": [
      {
        "product": "63f7a3e617e06f25949568fa",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 4000,
        "_id": "63f89ef6d806216d1e672628"  // this is id I'm asking about??
      }
    ],
    "shippingAddress": {
      "street": "",
      "city": "String",
      "state": "String",
      "zip": "String",
      "country": "String"
    },
    "billingAddress": {
      "street": "String",
      "city": "String",
      "state": "String",
      "zip": "String",
      "country": "String"
    },
    "total": 4000,
    "status": "Not Deliverd",
    "_id": "63f89ef6d806216d1e672627", 
    "__v": 0
  },
  "message": "One order of id 2 has been created successfully. Go to your cart to modify your orders"
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field):

> In MongoDB, each document stored in a collection requires a unique _id field that acts as a primary key. If an inserted document omits the _id field, the MongoDB driver automatically generates an ObjectId for the _id field.

Comment: is it an id that acts like an index in the items array? If so, each item in the items array will have an _id?

Comment: Did it create a new document in the products array with that _id?